# Roblox gamepass prompt not showing up

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to make one of those stupid comedic Roblox games where the title is in all lowercase and stuff like that. The premise of this game is that you have to pay do literally anything; walking, jumping, opening doors, etc. I wrote a script that functions as follows: first it checks if you have the gamepass, then if you do not have the gamepass, it will open a buy prompt for the gamepass when you press w, a, s, or d. I have tried to run print statements to see if it is the gamepass prompt call that is not working or if it is something else like the keystroke detection, but to no avail. (By the way, it is in a localscript with a disabled script called 'walkspeednew' that sets your walkspeed to normal after you buy the gamepass. The script called 'WalkSpeed' runs when you start the game, and sets your walkspeed to 0.)

```
local ps=game:GetService("Players")
local gamePassId=26063683
ps.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local hasPass=false
    local success,message=pcall(function()
        hasPass=MarketplaceService:UserOwnsGamepassAsync(player.UserId,gamePassId)
    end)
    if not success then
        warn('gamepass loading error')
        return
    end
    if hasPass then
        game.Workspace.WalkSpeed:Destroy()
        script.walkspeednew.Disabled=false
    end
end
UserInput.InputBegan:Connect(function(input,gameProccesedevent)
    if not hasPass then
        if input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.W or input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.A or input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.S or input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.D then
            local player=game.Players.LocalPlayer
            Game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptPurchase(player,gamePassId)
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not handy to use UserInput for this. The Humanoid has a property called [MoveDirection](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Humanoid/MoveDirection) which determines, as a unit vector, the direction a player is moving in. You can access the Magnitude property and see if it’s greater than 0 to know if there is active movement without relying on what their HumanoidStateType or UserInput is.